# How to handle this Gql query object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

```
user_exists = db.GqlQuery("select * from User where user_id in '%s'" % username)
```

I'm trying to do a test to see if a particular user id (user_id) already exists in the database(User). Basically, if 'user_exists' holds any results, I want to produce an error and re-render the form, and if it's empty, I want to continue on with storing a users data. How can I tell if 'user_exists' contains a result or not?

I have tried,

```
if user_exists:
```

but this condition passes every time. That is, it is always true for every name I pass in, whether it already exists or not.

I also tried,

```
if len(user_exists) > 0:
```

but get the error that a Gql query object has no len. If user_exists is a Gql query object, how could I extract some sort of list from this in order to simply check it's contents in the way I am attempting to?

I have in the past iterated through such an object with a for loop in a jinja template, and I assumed that this object could also be treated like an iterable, such as a list, in general.

Comment: One thing to note - This approach "using queries" will not guarantee you won't create duplicate user_id's  consider using the user_id as the key of the entity. This will then allow you to do a get_by_id which is far more efficient and you can't then have duplicates.

Comment: This had crossed my mind, but I am unsure how to do it. No excuse for me not looking this up in the docs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would work if you were calling `.get()` or `.fetch(1)` on the GqlQuery object.

Example:

```
user = db.GqlQuery("select * from User where user_id = :1", username).get()
if user:
    # now `user` will contain a value if the query returns a value or None if not
```

You should prefer use of query parameters to string-interpolation as using the API makes your code less vulnerable to SQL-injection attack.

Comment: When you mention string-interpolation above, are you referring to the use of %s?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: `'this is %s interpolation' % 'string'` http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations